# Asynchronous iOS networking library design

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm facing a design decision while developing an iPhone app library for which I'd appreciate feedback for. Basically, I'm developing an asynchronous HTTP client library for a REST API.

My question is: 
**What's the recommended way to return the parsed data from the library back to the calling code?**

Synchronously would simply:
    NSArray *users = [restLibrary getAllUsers]
where getAllUsers is declared as:
    - (NSArray *)getAllUsers;

or for custom objects
    User *tom = [restLibrary getUser:@"tom"]
if getUser: is declared as:
    - (User *)getUser:(NSString *)userName;

I'm confused about how to do it cleanly asynchronously.

I came across this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962502/ios-design-using-the-delegate-pattern-in-a-library) with the same exact question. The original poster found a solution but he/she is not sure whether is the recommended one.

Thanks for your help.

Jorge

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using asynchronous calls, you wait for a callback. This basically means you ask a class to start doing something and when it's done it should execute a method of your choice.

A good example of this is Apple's own NSUrlConnection class. You provide this class with a delegate. This is basically an object that the NSUrlConnection class will execute methods on as appropriate.

So

```
NSURLRequest *  req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: self.url];
self.downloadConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: req
                                                        delegate: self];
[self.downloadConnection start];
```

This tells the NSUrlConnection class to fetch the data at self.url and that it should use the current class as a delegate.

There are several methods on the delegate, called under certain circumstances, the most frequent one probably being

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *) connection
{

}
```

For your class, you would do something similar. You would first define a @protocol to represent the interface you would use. In your example, this may have a method like

```
- (void)userFetched:(User *)user
```

You then execute your restLibrary with a method similar to

```
[restLibrary getUser:@"tom" delegate:self]
```

And the calling class should implement the userFetched method.

In your getUser method on restLibrary, you would execute the actual call to fetch the data (most likely using NSUrlConnection asychronously and parsing the returned data into a User object) and then invoke userFetched with the result.

You would need to implement other methods to handle error conditions and such.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes!, thanks tomas. I was completely overlooking the @protocol definition. Things make sense now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have requirements to roll your own... I would only use the open source lib ASIHTTP.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

its very solid.